# get nested json response

Tags: php, json

I have table `store_profile` like this

```
id Storename        Storetype        address
1  Samsung Store    Electronics      Delhi
2  Levi             Clothing         Mumbai
3  Soni             Electronics      Bangalore
```

and second table `Offers`

```
id Store_id         offer           price
1  Samsung Store    flat 30% off     20000
2  Levi             Exchange         5000
3  Samsung Store    Exchange offer   40000
```

I want to get all the store details from `store_profile` for particular type,say *Electronics* and for each store their offers in single row,not repeated as I am getting from this syntax in json mysql query is :-

```
SELECT * , Offers.Store_id
FROM Store_profile INNER JOIN
     Offers
     ON Store_profile.Storename = Offers.Store_id AND
        Store_profile.Storetype like '%Electronics%'
```

Here is my php code

```
$sql ="SELECT * , Offers.Store_id FROM Store_profile INNER JOIN Offers ON Store_profile.Storename = Offers.Store_id AND Store_profile.Storetype like '%Electronics%' LIMIT 0 , 300 ";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    array_push($result,array(
        'Store_Name'=>$row['Storename'],
        'Store_address'=>$row['address'],
        'Offer_Title'=>$row['offer'],
        'MRP_Price'=>$row['price'],
        )
    );
}
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Can you show us the output you want to obtain?

Comment: ye...i want to get json like this result["Storename"-Samsung Store,Store_address - Delhi,Offer[Offer_Title-Flat 30% Off,MRP_Price20000,Offer_Title-Exchange offer,MRP_Price40000 ]]
i want to get offer for Store samsung in a nested offer array...but i am getting samsung store two times...i want to get samsung store detail single time and multiple offer inside it

Comment: It's a better idea to edit the question, as we can't see code blocks properly in comments - think of this question as surviving beyond your needs to provide help to others who may encounter the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... i want to get json like this result["Storename"-Samsung Store,Store_address - Delhi,Offer[Offer_Title-Flat 30% Off,MRP_Price20000,Offer_Title-Exchange offer,MRP_Price40000 ]]

Change your `while()` loop and the subsequent `json_encode()` function call in the following way,

```
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    if(!isset($result[$row['Store_id']])){
        $result[$row['Store_id']] = array('Store_Name'=>$row['Storename'], 'Store_address'=>$row['address']);
    }
    $result[$row['Store_id']]['offer'][] = array('Offer_Title'=>$row['offer'],'MRP_Price'=>$row['price']);
}

echo json_encode(array('result' => array_values($result)));
```

### Update:

From your comment,

> ... i have one store in store_profile but this store doesnt have any offer in Offers table. I am not getting this store's data in my json

You have to use `LEFT JOIN` to include all the *matched* rows from the `Store_profile` table in the result set. Furthermore, you need to use `WHERE` instead of `AND` after the joining condition. So your query should be like this:

```
SELECT * , Offers.Store_id 
FROM Store_profile 
LEFT JOIN Offers 
ON Store_profile.Storename = Offers.Store_id 
WHERE Store_profile.Storetype LIKE '%Electronics%' 
LIMIT 0 , 300
```

Subsequently, change your `while()` loop and `json_encode()` function call in the following way,

```
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    if(!isset($result[$row['Storename']])){
        $result[$row['Storename']] = array('Store_Name'=>$row['Storename'], 'Store_address'=>$row['address']);
    }
    if(isset($row['offer']) && isset($row['price'])){
        $result[$row['Storename']]['offer'][] = array('Offer_Title'=>$row['offer'],'MRP_Price'=>$row['price']);
    }else{
        $result[$row['Storename']]['offer'] = array();
    }
}

echo json_encode(array('result' => array_values($result)));
```

Comment: @rajdeep_paul

{"result"[{Store_Name":"SamsungExclusiveStore","Store_address":null,"offer":[{"Offer_Title":"Samsung Store","MRP_Price":"1234"}]},{"Store_Name":"qwertyuio","Store_address":null,"offer":[{"Offer_Title":"Sony Mobile","MRP_Price":"1999"}]},{"Store_Name":"Hometown","Store_address":null,"offer"[{"Offer_Title":"Buy LED at 25% flat Discount","MRP_Price":"40"}]}{"Store_Name":"SamsungExclusiveStore","Store_address":null,"offer":[{"Offer_Title":"Samsung TV""MRP_Price":"999"}]}]}
i wnt offer for samsung stor to b in a nested array,not samsng store to be displayed twice,please hlp me out

Comment: @Abhishekshrivastava I've updated my answer. Please test your application with the updated code snippet.

Comment: @rajdeep_paul  thankyou so much for ur reply...u saved me..A big big thanks to you

Comment: @Abhishekshrivastava You're very welcome! ;-) Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: @rajdeep_paul here is one more issue....i have one store in store_profile but this store doesnt have any offer in Offers table. I am not getting this store's data in my json...please have a look

Comment: @Abhishekshrivastava I've updated my answer. Please see the **Update** section of my answer.

Comment: @rajdeep_paul thanks a lot...i have corrected the joins...thankyou so much....can i ask u one more thing...?m sorry for troubling you again and again...if possible can u please clear my one more doubt...that would be very kind of you....

Comment: @Abhishekshrivastava Sure, what is it?

Comment: i have multiple images for a particular store in Store_Profile...I am using this to separate
 'storeimages'=>array(
                      'imagename'=>explode(',',$row['storeimages'])
               
)
i am getting this json
"storeimages":{"imagename":["ab.jpg","b.jpg"]}
but i want json like this  
storeimages":{"imagename":"ab.jpg","Imagename":b.jpg"}
how to do this?

Comment: @Abhishekshrivastava Paste your code on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/index.php) and give me it's link here.

Comment: @Abhishekshrivastava Think about it, your requirement is not possible since you can't have two different values in the array with same index key. It's better that you keep them that way.

Comment: @rajdeep_paul yes u r correct...i was just expecting if there is any other way...Thankyou so much for all the help...thankyou

Comment: @Abhishekshrivastava You're welcome! Glad I could help. ;-)